# SplashScreen.hide() is deprecated in favour of SplashScreen.hideAsync()

Tags: react-native, expo

After ejecting from Expo to bare workflow , I am getting these two warnings

[SplashScreen.hide() is deprecated in favour of SplashScreen.hideAsync()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoaX3.png)

[SplashScreen.preventAutoHide() is deprecated in favour of SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
at AppLoading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XLVB.png)

Answer (score 1):

change `SplashScreen.hide()` to `SplashScreen.hideAsync()` and `SplashScreen.preventAutoHide()` to `SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()` (this is what the warnings are telling you to do)

Comment: thanks for early response , what I found useful in my case is what i mentioned below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How i am able to resolve this issue is defined below,

first go to this location

```
node_modules/expo/build/launch/SplashScreen.js
```

your file will look like this:

```
    export * from 'expo-splash-screen';
    //# sourceMappingURL=SplashScreen.js.map
```

change the above code to this

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
export function preventAutoHide() {
    if (SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync) {
        SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    }
}
export function hide() {
    if (SplashScreen.hideAsync) {
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=SplashScreen.js.map
```

now close your metro bundler and rerun command `yarn ios/android`

and you are good to go,

Happy coding ;-)